# draw count increasing abnormally

Tags: ios, optimization, sprite-kit

I'm currently developing a Sprite Kit game which scrolls between two main screen A & B. A's position is (0, 0) and B position is (0, device_height).

Most of the time, the game is running 60fps and draw count (got with `SKView::showsDrawCount` property) at 8 or 10.
But sometimes, only on B screen, the number of draws increase abnormally to 70-80 draws!

Here's some facts:

- I don't remove A screen nodes when I'm showing B because A nodes continue to affect the physics.
- I'm using SKTextureAtlas and I preloaded all the texture in a dictionary for optimisation purpose
- Even with decorative node removed (particules, backgrounds), the draw count increase occurs.
- When the bug occurs, non-culled node count increase significantly (given by `SKView::showsNodeCount`), but my real node count (found by using `[node::children count]` recursively) is stable.

Does someone had been confronted to the problematic, and what optimizations can be done?

How can I have more information about those draws to see where do they come from?

Thanks

**EDIT :**

Just found something very interesting. Here's the processor usage over time, switching between screen A and B. We can see there's a certain Thread-14 whose doing lots of things!

[image: processor over time]

Comment: well you have to ask yourself.. whats the difference from B screen compared to A screen?  I had major optimization problems in my game (i still have a few minor ones).  Only way I can figure out whats causing problems is to turn things on or off, and observe performance.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i'm doing: turning thing on & off... The strange thing is there is no difference between A & B. [A B] is just one SKScene whose height is twice the device one. I suspect there's is a bug with the spritekit cullig system but it's too easy to say that's comes from the sdk.

Comment: Are you adding nodes without removing them later? Maybe post some relevant code. It could be a lot of stuff

Comment: Of course, my node count is stable. When the bug occurs, non-culled node count increase significantly (given by `SKView::showsNodeCount`), but my real node count (found by using `[node::children count]` recursively) is stable.

Comment: Is your skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES; ?

Comment: @sangory I tried without significant changes : the bug was still there. Do you think I should manage zPosition manually anyways?

Comment: Are you using shapeNodes to draw content? Each shape is broken down into triangles which are drawn individually, so shapeNodes can massively increase the draw count.

Comment: @Okapi Yes, I'm a few shapeNodes to create the ground. Their pathes cumulate 10-20 points, not more. Could they have something with the thread activity in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it!

I'm using some `SKEffectNode`s as roots of the node trees whose never change, with the property `shouldRasterize = YES` (for caching purpose, I saw this tip on the web but I can't remember where. But now I wonder if this is really appropriated... what do you think?).

I noticed that the `shouldEnableEffects` properties of these nodes were all set to YES after init, despite the description in Apple documentation:

> If the value of this property is YES, the effect node applies the
>   filter and blends the results. If the value is NO, the effect node is
>   ignored and its children are rendered normally. The default value is
>   NO.

Obviously Apple doc is wrong for the default value at least on iOS8.

I presume the crazy thread was handling some blending effects, because after setting every `SKEffectNode::shouldEnableEffects` to NO, the thread never came back. However, I still don't understand why the bug only occurred on screen B.